# How to check the function params which is an anonymous function using toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I want to test a function which just return a function with some values and an anonymous function as parameters. How to test the match for the anonymous function using toHaveBeenCalledWith in jest?

```js
function toBeTested( id, values) {
 return xyz(id, values, () => {
  return { 
    type: 'foo', 
    payload: { 
     text: values.text
    }
  }
 })
}
```

In my test

```js
describe('test for toBeTested',  () => {
  it('should call xyz with params', () => {
    const id = 123;
    const values = {
      text: 'Hello world',
    };

   xyz = jest.fn();
   toBeTested(id, values);
    expect(xyz).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id, values, () => {
     return {
      type: 'foo',
      payload: {
       text: values.text,
      }
     }
    });
  })
})
```

Test error report

```sh
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [123, {text: 'Hello world'}, [Function anonymous]]
    But it was called with:
      [123, {text: 'Hello world'}, [Function anonymous]]

      at Object.it.only (src/actions/tests/xyz.test.js:30:43)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and I found this question which the selected answer didn't help me. So I decided to write an answer with what solved my problem hoping it can help other people.

TL;DR: use `expect.any(Function)` as below:

```
    expect(xyz).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      id,
      values,
      expect.any(Function)
    );
```

Full answer:

The selected answer is indeed an alternative for situations in which you can receive a callback, however there are other scenarios in which the anonymous function shouldn't be exposed or even provided by the caller function.

Example:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

export const runScript = (data: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`a script to be called with this data ${data}`, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        // handle error
        // ...
        reject();
      } else {
        // do something
        // ...
        resolve('result');
      }
    });
  });
};
```

in the example above I don't want to receive the error handling function as an callback since that logic is really intrinsic to the `runScript` function and it shouldn't be implemented or provided by an external caller function. The real function would have more logic in it, but I believe sharing its structure already gives an idea that those scenarios exist.

NOTE: the `// ...` parts in my code have more logic, calling external functions which I'm able to mock and assert what's being passed to them, so I can test it properly. I just removed it for the sake of simplifying it

Anyway, here's how I managed to test it:

```
expect(execMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  '...',
  expect.any(Function),
);
```

In the your case @manikandan-j, it would be:

```
it('should call xyz with params', () => {
    const id = 123;
    const values = {
      text: 'Hello world',
    };

    xyz = jest.fn();
    toBeTested(id, values);
    expect(xyz).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      id,
      values,
      expect.any(Function)
    );
  });
});
```

Also, if you use `expect.any(Function)` (as I'm using) and you want to test the content of your anonymous function

```
() => {
  return { 
    type: 'foo', 
    payload: { 
    text: values.text
  }
}
```

you would test the result of `toBeTested` that would be impacted by those values. Something like the below:

```
    const result = toBeTested(id, values);
    expect(xyz).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      id,
      values,
      expect.any(Function)
    );
    expect(result).toBe(...);
```

Anyway, I hope it helps people testing functions that one of its arguments is an anonymous function that cannot be received as an argument.

Comment: Amazing 